# How do I get Python XML to stop having wasted Child Nodes

Tags: python, xml, whitespace, nodes

I have a simple XML document I'm trying to read in with Python DOM (see below):

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HeaderLookup>
    <Header>
        <Reserved>2</Reserved>
        <CPU>1</CPU>
        <Flag>1</Flag>
        <VQI>12</VQI>
        <Group_ID>16</Group_ID>
        <DI>2</DI>
        <DE>1</DE>
        <ACOSS>5</ACOSS>
        <RGH>8</RGH>
    </Header>
</HeaderLookup>
```

**Python Code:**

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xml_file = open("test.xml")
xmlroot = minidom.parse(xml_file).documentElement
xml_file.close()

for item in xmlroot.getElementsByTagName("Header")[0].childNodes:
    print item
```

**Result:**

```
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: Reserved at 0x28d2828>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: CPU at 0x28d28c8>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: Flag at 0x28d2968>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: VQI at 0x28d2a08>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: Group_ID at 0x28d2ad0>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: DI at 0x28d2b70>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: DE at 0x28d2c10>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: ACOSS at 0x28d2cb0>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t\t'">
<DOM Element: RGH at 0x28d2d50>
<DOM Text node "u'\n\t'">
```

The result should be 9 Child Nodes (Reserved, CPU, Flag, VQI, Group_ID, DI, DE, ACOSS, and RGH), but for some reason it is returning a list of 19 nodes with 10 of them being whitespace (why is this even being considered a node in the first place?!).  Can anyone tell me if there's a way to get the XML parser to not include whitespace nodes?

Comment: Why are nodes containing only whitespace being included in the list of child nodes? Because the text within an element is a child of the element. DOM has no way of knowing you're not interested in all children. It would be nice if DOM had `childElements` as well as `childNodes`, I guess, but it is trivial to write your own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whitespace is significant in XML, but check out [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), which has a different API for processing XML than the DOM.

#### Example

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

data = '''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HeaderLookup>
    <Header>
        <Reserved>2</Reserved>
        <CPU>1</CPU>
        <Flag>1</Flag>
        <VQI>12</VQI>
        <Group_ID>16</Group_ID>
        <DI>2</DI>
        <DE>1</DE>
        <ACOSS>5</ACOSS>
        <RGH>8</RGH>
    </Header>
</HeaderLookup>
'''

tree = et.fromstring(data)
for n in tree.find('Header'):
    print n.tag,'=',n.text
```

#### Output

```
Reserved = 2
CPU = 1
Flag = 1
VQI = 12
Group_ID = 16
DI = 2
DE = 1
ACOSS = 5
RGH = 8
```

#### Example (extending previous code)

The whitespace is still present, but it is in `.tail` attributes.  `tail` is the text node that follows an element (between the end of one element and the start of the next), while `text` is the text node between the start/end tag of an element.

```
def dump(e):
    print '<%s>' % e.tag
    print 'text =',repr(e.text)
    for n in e:
        dump(n)
    print '</%s>' % e.tag
    print 'tail =',repr(e.tail)

dump(tree)
```

#### Output

```
<HeaderLookup>
text = '\n    '
<Header>
text = '\n        '
<Reserved>
text = '2'
</Reserved>
tail = '\n        '
<CPU>
text = '1'
</CPU>
tail = '\n        '
<Flag>
text = '1'
</Flag>
tail = '\n        '
<VQI>
text = '12'
</VQI>
tail = '\n        '
<Group_ID>
text = '16'
</Group_ID>
tail = '\n        '
<DI>
text = '2'
</DI>
tail = '\n        '
<DE>
text = '1'
</DE>
tail = '\n        '
<ACOSS>
text = '5'
</ACOSS>
tail = '\n        '
<RGH>
text = '8'
</RGH>
tail = '\n    '
</Header>
tail = '\n'
</HeaderLookup>
tail = None
```